# Submitting Repeating InfoPath Table to Sharepoint list in Browser Enabled Form

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, infopath

Hopefully you can help. I am working on a Browser Enabled InfoPath 2010 form that lives in a Document Library on a SharePoint site (2007 and 2010). In this form there is a repeating table with data that needs to be captured for reporting purposes. The solution I have chosen is to use the built in SharePoint lists.asmx Web Service to write the lines in the repeating table to a separate list on the sane SharePoint site, in the same site collection. I used the steps here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc162745(v=office.12).aspx, as my baseline.

I have gotten everything set up and working when run directly from the InfoPath form client site. The form opens and, on submit, the rows in the repeating table are written to the SharePoint list without any problems. However, once I deploy the form through Central Admin and test, none of the rows in the repeating table are getting written to the list. There are no errors or anything to indicate a problem with the code, and a boolean field used to indicate whether or not a row has been uploaded is set to true.

My first thought is that there is a problem with the permissions somewhere. Maybe when the service is called from client side it passes my credentials but when run from the server through the Document Library it's using something different? Shouldn't it use the credentials that are used to gain access to the SharePoint (which are also my AD credentials)? Is there a way to specify the use of the current users AD credentials when calling the lists.asmx web service in the code?

Anyway, not really sure where else to go with this. Any searching I do comes up with the same how two documentation on submitting to a SharePoint list in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code I am using to accomplish this.

```
if (MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:ShippingInformation/my:ShipDate", NamespaceManager).Value != "")
            {
                // If Ship Date is not blank, upload items in Material used to SP List where ForQuote is False
                // Quote Number, RMA Number, Ship Date, Unit S/N,

                // Create a WebServiceConnection object for submitting 
                // to the Lists Web service data connection.
                WebServiceConnection wsSubmit =
                   (WebServiceConnection)this.DataConnections["Material Web Service Submit"];

                //Create XPathNodeIterator object for the new Material Lines
                XPathNodeIterator MaterialLines = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().Select("/my:myFields/my:RepairQuote/my:QuoteLines/my:QuoteLine", NamespaceManager);
                int lineCount = 0;

                foreach (XPathNavigator NewLines in MaterialLines)
                {
                    lineCount += 1;
                    if (NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:ForQuote", NamespaceManager).Value == "false" && NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:LineSubmitted", NamespaceManager).Value == "false")
                    {
                        // Set the values in the Add List Item Template 
                        // XML file using the values in the new row.
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='Title']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:lineItem", NamespaceManager).Value);
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='RMANumber']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:EntitlementContainer/my:RMANumber", NamespaceManager).Value);
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='UnitSerialNumber']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:EntitlementContainer/my:serialNumber", NamespaceManager).Value);
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='ShipDate']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:ShippingInformation/my:ShipDate", NamespaceManager).Value);
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='OrderType']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:RepairQuote/my:orderType", NamespaceManager).Value);
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='QuoteNumber']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:RepairQuote/my:quoteNumber", NamespaceManager).Value);
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='LineQuantity']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:lineQuantity", NamespaceManager).Value);
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='LineNumber']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(lineCount.ToString());

                        // Set the value of Cmd attribute to "New".
                        DataSources["AddListItemTemplate"].CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/@Cmd", NamespaceManager).SetValue("New");

                        // Submit the new row.
                        wsSubmit.Execute();
                        NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:LineSubmitted", NamespaceManager).SetValue("true");
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: please post an example of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if it is the answer per se, but I believe the problem was related to security on the site. I got around this by using the SharePoint Object Model instead of the web service to create the list items (See http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/how-to-use-sharepoint-object-model-submit-data-infopath-browser-form-sharepoint-list.htm). With the SharePoint Object Model I am able to use AllowUnsafeUpdates. Also, where it took me quite a bit of time to get the web service set up, including the data connections, CAML file, etc. This way, however, only took a few minutes. Lesson learned, use the SharePoint Object Model if at all possible.

```
foreach (XPathNavigator NewLines in MaterialLines)
                {
                    lineCount += 1;
                    if (NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:ForQuote", NamespaceManager).Value == "false" && NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:LineSubmitted", NamespaceManager).Value == "false")
                    {

                        using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
                        {
                            if (site != null)
                            {
                                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                                {
                                    // Turn on AllowUnsafeUpdates on the site
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                    // Update the SharePoint list based on the values
                                    // from the InfoPath form
                                    SPList list = web.GetList("/Lists/InfoPathRtpItems");

                                    if (list != null)
                                    {
                                        SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
                                        item["Title"] = NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:lineItem", NamespaceManager).Value;
                                        item["RMANumber"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:EntitlementContainer/my:RMANumber", NamespaceManager).Value;
                                        item["UnitSerialNumber"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:EntitlementContainer/my:serialNumber", NamespaceManager).Value;
                                        item["ShipDate"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:ShippingInformation/my:ShipDate", NamespaceManager).Value;
                                        item["OrderType"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:RepairQuote/my:orderType", NamespaceManager).Value;
                                        item["QuoteNumber"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("./my:myFields/my:RepairQuote/my:quoteNumber", NamespaceManager).Value;
                                        item["LineQuantity"] = NewLines.SelectSingleNode(".//my:lineQuantity", NamespaceManager).Value;
                                        item["LineNumber"] = lineCount.ToString();
                                        item.Update();
                                    }

                                    // Turn off AllowUnsafeUpdates on the site
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                                    // Close the connection to the site
                                    web.Close();
                                }

                                // Close the connection to the site collection
                                site.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why the code doesn't work when you deploy and call the lists web service in code. However I would suggest you to try debugging it to get to the root of the problem:

[Step by Step – Debug InfoPath 2010 Forms Deployed on SharePoint 2010 Using Visual Studio 2010](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2011/07/)

Please try this out and step through it to see if it goes through the code as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will give this a shot and post back the results.

Comment: I was able to follow the steps in the link you provided up to Step 2. After that it seems like there is something missing. I rename the published XSN file after verifying the PDB file is included. I go the SharePoint Site Collection's Central Admin and upload the form. Then I navigate to the SharePoint List where the form is used. I open up the .cs file of the form, Attach to Process, Attach to Managed Code, check show all processes and all sessions, and there are no w3wp.exe processes listed. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio on the Sharepoint Server itself?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. This is still an issue. I am only able to run Visual Studio from my Local Mahine as I do not have access to the Server itself.